# PowerShell command prints the value rather than executing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have written a power shell command to achieve a specific function and I'm new to power shell.
That should perform the action and I'm pretty sure I have entered exact working command.
But when I try to execute the command inside for each loop, it prints the command rather than executing. NWAdminCommand is my command and it gets values from user input.

```
$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action"

foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {

      foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
         {
    $NWAdminCommand;
         }
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to understand:

your asking:

> Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action:

i then type ali and it would loop through each subsite within the given site (i have 5):

so the result should be:

> ali
>
> ali
>
> ali
>
> ali
>
> ali

solution:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action"

$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://mywebapplication:23125/

foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
    {
        $NWAdminCommand;
    }
}
```

above needs to be within a file witht the extention of .ps1 , run that file within powershell! code has been tested on my server, if your looking for somthing else than please do refine your question :)

if you want to ask that question for each site looped than its in the wrong location... i dont see why you want to print the same reply for each site looped and print the same result to screen:

solution:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://mywebapplication:23125/

foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
    {
        $NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action"

        //do what you want with the varible $NWAdminCommand related to site $SPWeb
    }
}
```

above would ask the question for each site, that varible (answer) is now only related to that site and is reset every site that is iterated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work. But have you tried to use Invoke-Expression

The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command and returns the results of the expression or command. Without Invoke-Expression, a string submitted at the command line would be returned (echoed) unchanged.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx

```
$cmd = '& 7z.exe a -tzip "c:\temp\with space\test2.zip" "C:\TEMP\with space\changelog"'

Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592851/executing-a-command-stored-in-a-variable-from-powershell